# Python - Extract from .plist

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I got this piece of code, a .plist.
Is there a way for me to extract certain sections of it?
I only want the strings, and if possible, just some certain strings.

Like if I could extract `-(bool) isAgent`
Knowing `<key>displayName</key>` is above it, and `<key>prefix</key>` under it.

```
                <string>ZDKUser</string>
                <key>displayName</key>
                <string>-(bool) isAgent</string>
                <key>prefix</key>
```

Out of this block ^

Is this possible? How would I do it? 
If not possible with python, how else?

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UUID</key>
            <string>123-456-789-0123</string>
            <key>purchaseNumber</key>
            <string>y.number.x</string>
            <key>purchaseID</key>
            <string>3.5.6</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>*Product Name*</string>
            <key>purchased</key>
            <false/>
            <key>units</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>methodObjc</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>className</key>
                        <string>ZDKUser</string>
                        <key>displayName</key>
                        <string>-(bool) isAgent</string>
                        <key>prefix</key>
                        <string>-</string>
                        <key>selector</key>
                        <string>isAgent</string>
                        <key>typeEncoding</key>
                        <string>B16@0:8</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Unit for -(bool) isAgent</string>
                    <key>overrides</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>argument</key>
                            <integer>0</integer>
                            <key>type</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>subtype</key>
                                <integer>0</integer>
                                <key>type</key>
                                <integer>6</integer>
                            </dict>
                            <key>value</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>type</key>
                                <integer>6</integer>
                                <key>value</key>
                                <true/>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>methodObjc</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>className</key>
                        <string>AFUserAccount</string>
                        <key>displayName</key>
                        <string>-(void) setAuto_renew:(bool)</string>
                        <key>prefix</key>
                        <string>-</string>
                        <key>selector</key>
                        <string>setAuto_renew:</string>
                        <key>typeEncoding</key>
                        <string>v20@0:8B16</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Unit for -(void) setAuto_renew:(bool)</string>
                    <key>overrides</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>argument</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                            <key>type</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>subtype</key>
                                <integer>0</integer>
                                <key>type</key>
                                <integer>6</integer>
                            </dict>
                            <key>value</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>type</key>
                                <integer>6</integer>
                                <key>value</key>
                                <true/>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
<array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Use plistlib library.
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html Or alternatively you can read the Plist file and loop in to take the content after first occurrence of <key>...</key> and before the next tag you expect to read till. I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: Dowload the plistlib.py file to your local machine and import from local.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a real beginner to this, how do I do that? ^ :(

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html
Right click on the Plistlib hyperlink click on savelinkecontent as, this will download the .py library to your local PC. then write import path/plistlib.py where you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import sys

doc = etree.parse(open(sys.argv[1]))
for app_dict in doc.xpath('/plist/dict/array/dict'):
    appId = app_dict.xpath('./key[.="appIdentifier"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0]
    for method_dict in app_dict.xpath('.//dict[key="methodObjc"]/dict'):
        classId = method_dict.xpath('./key[.="className"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0]
        methodId = method_dict.xpath('./key[.="displayName"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0] 
        print 'App: %s; Class: %s; Method: %s' % (appId, classId, methodId)
```

Answer by @Charles Duffy